# Retrieving source code of site in InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

When opening a website in the InAppBrowser, is there a way to retrieve the source code of the website?

This is needed for a PhoneGap app for iOs.

I was thinking either by a javascript injection that could read and return the source, or by writing it in objective c and make a plugin - if either of these options would be possible.

Comment: I think there is no way to retrieve data from InAppBrowser page back to your application :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by injecting js script after page load event is fired in InAppBrowser.

```
var code = 'javascript:alert("xxxxxxx")';
var ref = window.open('YOUR PAGE', '_blank', 'location=yes');
                    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { 
                            //wait 1 second till page load
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                    ref.executeScript({
                                            code: code,
                                    }, function() {
                                            console.log('script was injected successfully');
                                    });
                            }, 1000);

                    });
```

replace variable 'code' value with your code to scrap the whole page, I mean something like this:

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

then send the variable 'markup' value to your server